# What is the actual type of JSON like object in C# (new {};)

Tags: c#

I was learning C# and found that there is some type of value defined by

```cs
var json = new {name="App", age=20};
```

Although this seems to be similar to the JSON type. But when I tried to use the GetType method, I got **<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]**

Can anyone help me in this please?

In case you want the full code

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new { name="App", age=22 };

        Console.WriteLine(c.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(c);;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), you can find more information at [Anonymous Types C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250314/anonymous-types-c-sharp) and [How to dynamic new Anonymous Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740021/how-to-dynamic-new-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called `Anonymous Type` and it has no relation to JSON.

You can read about it FROM [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is
>   not available at the source code level. The type of each property is
>   inferred by the compiler.